# grep exact pattern from a file in bash

Tags: bash, grep

I have the following IP addresses in a file

```
3.3.3.1
3.3.3.11
3.3.3.111
```

I am using this file as input file to another program. In that program it will `grep` each IP address. But when I `grep` the contents I am getting some wrong outputs.

like

```
cat testfile | grep -o 3.3.3.1
```

but I am getting output like

```
3.3.3.1
3.3.3.1
3.3.3.1
```

I just want to get the exact output. How can I do that with `grep`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following command:

```
grep -owF "3.3.3.1" tesfile
```

`-o` returns the match only and not the whole line.`-w` greps for whole words, meaning the match must be enclosed in non word chars like `<space>`, `<tab>`, `,`, `;` the start or the end of the line etc. It prevents grep from matching `3.3.3.1` out of `3.3.3.111`.

`-F` greps for fixed strings instead of patterns. This prevents the `.` in the IP address to be interpreted as *any char*, meaning `grep` will not match `3a3b3c1` (or something like this).

Comment: may also be useful to use anchors: `^3.3.3.1$`

Comment: @fedorqui It depends on what the OP wants to do. Basically the `-w` and the `-F` options are important.

Comment: Yes, specially `-F` not to match a dot with any character.

Answer (score 1):

To match whole words only, use `grep -ow 3.3.3.1 testfile`

<sup>*UPDATE: Use the solution provided by [hek2mgl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/171318/hek2mgl) as it is more robust.*</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You may use anhcors.

```
grep '^3\.3\.3\.1$' file
```

Since by default grep uses regex, you need to escape the dots in-order to make grep to match literal dot character.